# Port number 5300 not woking in DNS client

Tags: c, dns

I'm making a DNS client and connecting it to a server. Whenever I provide port number 53(default for DNS server) it works fine.. But, whenever I provide port number 5300, the program freezes. Port number 5300 is asked to provide in the question for which I'm doing this code.
So, can anybody help why does my client freezes when I provide port 5300?
I'm using C language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your code, I can't be 100% certain. I'm assuming that when you say you switch to port 5300, you're setting in both the client AND the server. Also, is the port listening on the server UDP instead of TCP? If you haven't already, try running *netstat* on your server to see what ports it is listening on.